# Angular Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Number' ...but it never is a string

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

views is the property with the issue

Here is the template of the child component (being iterated over)

mnemonicCard.html

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-title>{{name}}</ion-card-title>
    <ion-icon name="eye">{{views}}</ion-icon>
</ion-card>
```

and here is the code:

```
@Component({
    selector:'app-mnemonicCard',
    standalone:true,
    templateUrl:"./mnemonicCard.html",
    imports:[
        IonicModule,
        CommonModule
    ]
})
export class MnemonicCard {
    @Input() name: String = '';
    @Input() views: Number = 0;
}

export interface Mnemonic{
    link: String
    name: String
    stars: Number
    views: Number
    globalViewRank: Number
    globalStarRank: Number
    collectionViewRank?: Number
    collectionStarRank?: Number
}
```

The message points to the template of the parent component SingleCollectionPage.

line 21 view={{m.views}}

That section looks like this:

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <app-mnemonicCard *ngFor="let m of this.collection.mnemonics"
  name={{m.name}}
  views={{m.views}}
  ></app-mnemonicCard>
</ion-content>
```

and the parent component's code:

```
export class SingleCollectionPage{
    @Input() id = '' 
    collection: Collection = {id: '1', name: 'Loading...'}
    constructor(private collectionService: CollectionService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        console.log('input', this.id)
        this.collectionService.getCollectionByID(this.id, true).then(c => {
            
            this.collection = c;
            console.log(this.collection)  //Yep these show as numbers in the console
  
    })
}
}

export interface Collection {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    mnemonicCount?: number,
    mnemonics?: Array<Mnemonic>
}
```

The collection has an Array, and Mnemonic's views property is a Number! So WTF is going on???

```
export interface Mnemonic{
    link: String
    name: String
    stars: Number
    views: Number
    globalViewRank: Number
    globalStarRank: Number
    collectionViewRank?: Number
    collectionStarRank?: Number
}
```

Even my Intellisense thinks that both sides are Numbers
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of observations that potentially could fix your problem.

When you reference a variable from your `typescript` component to its template HTML, you do it without using `this`, so in this case, it would be `ngFor="... of collection.mnemonics"`.

When you bind data to your own component attributes or HTML attributes, you should do it using `property binding` rather than string interpolation, `Property binding` is typically used when you want to set an element's property dynamically based on the component's data or logic. Given your code, it should be:

```html
<app-mnemonicCard *ngFor="let mnemonic of collection.mnemonics"
  [name]="mnemonic.name" 
  [views]="mnemonic.views"
></app-mnemonicCard
```

When you create your own data types with `interfaces`, you should use the primitive values rather than the wrapper type, so `number`/`string`/`boolean` are recommended

```js
export interface Collection {
 id: string;
 name: string;
 mnemonicCount?: number;
 mnemonics?: Mnemonic[]; // this is another way of declaring an array, with []
}
```

Comment: Thank you (that fixed it). I was definitely getting twisted on the syntax...the double quote syntax just feels so weird. I'm used to building a string with JS  i.e. let str = `blah blah ${someChunk} etc` and then updating the DOM -- iterating in the actual template is just something I need to get used to I guess. Is it possible to do it this other way around in Angular ("building" the HTML/DOM on the ts side)?

Answer (score 2):

I notice that your type definitions are using the Uppercase versions of `String` instead of `string`, and `Number` instead of `number`

This might be causing an issue too because those Uppercase ones you are using are the JS objects for string and number manipulation like `String.fromCharCode(9)` or `Number.isNaN(4)`

I'm surprised that works at all actually, it's odd that TypeScript allows you to do that.

```ts
interface ICorrectInterfaceTypes {
  name: string
  views: number
  isCool: boolean
}

interface IWrongInterfaceTypes {
  name: String
  views: Number
  isCool: Boolean
}
```